# check values of 2 arrays and save similar values in 3rd array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 arrays in JS ES6.

```
const array1 = [{
    "itemId": "1632",
    "SFDCid": "CLI-5234648"
}, {
    "itemId": "1514",
    "SFDCid": "CLI-5234649"
}, {
    "itemId": "1130",
    "LineNumber": "CLI-5234650"
}, {
    "itemId": "1248",
    "LineNumber": "CLI-5234651"
}, {
    "itemId": "1528",
    "LineNumber": "CLI-5234652"
}]

const array2 = [{
    "itemId": "1632",
    "LineNumber": "CLI-5234648",
    "lineStatus": ""
}, {
    "itemId": "1514",
    "LineNumber": "CLI-5234649",
    "lineStatus": ""
}, {
    "itemId": "1130",
    "LineNumber": "CLI-5234650",
    "lineStatus": ""
}, {
    "itemId": "1248",
    "LineNumber": "CLI-5234651",
    "lineStatus": ""
}, {
    "itemId": "1528",
    "LineNumber": "CLI-5234652",
    "lineStatus": ""
}]
```

I'm trying to create a loop where it will look through the ItemId and LineNumber values and which ever have similar values, it will assign those values in a different array.

Also, for array2, i want to check if lineStatus value is null or set to T.

I'm trying to build this solution in JS ES6. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do it, the brute force way is to iterate both arrays, the problem with that approach is that it's slow and has bad complexity. What I'd do instead is first create a hashmap of the second array, then iterate the first array and check if they have the same id and that `array2.lineStatus` is true. If so, push to a new array.

This way the time complexity is better, you only have to iterate through the array once. (Which is O(n) instead of O(n2))

```js
function createMap(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item.itemId] = item;
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

const array2Map = createMap(array2)

const array3 = [];

for (const item of array1) {
  const array2Item = array2Map[item.itemId];
  const sameLineNumber = array2Item.lineNumber === item.lineNumber;
  if (array2Item && sameLineNumber && array2Item.lineStatus) {
    array3.push(array2Item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest way

```js
// here is only one line of code you will need

const array3 = array1.filter((ar1) => ar1.itemId === array2.find((ar2) => ar2.itemId === ar1.itemId && ar2.LineNumber === ar1.LineNumber && ar2.lineStatus).itemId);
```